# how to implement color temperature &tint correction algorithm same as Photoshop using python

Tags: python, image-processing, color-scheme

I'm looking for an algorithm for color temperature and color tint correction slider just like in Photoshop. I read [wiki page about color temperature .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) and understood how to approximately calculate correlated color temperature(CCT) in XYZ-color space.

And I found [an alogirhtm](http://www.tannerhelland.com/4435/convert-temperature-rgb-algorithm-code/) for directly adjust color-temperature of RGB image, using approximation(of the color of specific color temperature) and alpha-blending(with original image and color temperature).
I also know how to [convert color temperature from the pre-calculated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884544/setting-color-temperature-for-a-given-image-like-in-photoshop) (I also referenced color temperature correcting algorithm in Imagemagick.)

and the color temperature histogram I got from various post is below.

[**image1:** color temperature from web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd6AS.png)

But in color temperature correction from Photoshop is quite different from ones above.

[**image2:** color temperature&tint slide from photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOdaQ.png)

using color-temperature correction from the web, I never could get the same effect of temperature correction on photoshop. because in other algorithms, when the temperature goes down, **orange(or red) color** is increased on the image, but in photoshop, **the yellow color** is increased. And I can't get yellowish image from other algorithms.

I'm really curious why this happens and hopefully wanna know how to programmatically get the same effect of color temperature & tint correction slider from photoshop.

Can anybody give me any clue?

Comment: I have a color temperature bash shell script that uses ImageMagick at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/colortemp/index.php that you could call from python subprocess

Comment: Also, ImageMagick has a tint function at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#tint. By the way, I doubt that anyone, but Adobe knows exactly what they have implemented in Photoshop. All you can do is try to emulate it as best you can.

Comment: @fmw42 thank you for your comment and your shell script. I understand there is no way to find out exactly what kind of math is behind photoshop algorihtm. But what I'm looking for is reason why the color temperature correction implementation could be **so different**  despite there is only one definition of color temperature.

Comment: `@Hyeonsoo Oh` Why do you say there is so much difference?  Difference between what approaches or software? Note that argument values and ranges may be defined differently for different algorithms. My colortemperature script can use one of two different tables, for example. What is your reference to it at ImageMagick. I do not see the link for that in your question.

Comment: @fmw42 As I mentioned above, the image you get from photoshop color temp correction and the image you get from your script are different. when you look at image 2, the **color chart** is very different from imageMagick's chart. if I use your script, you can get some orange-tinted image, but you can never get yellow-tinted image like photoshop. because color chart itself is very different.

Comment: `@Hyeonsoo Oh`  Thanks for the clarification. As I mentioned, I do not know what adobe is doing in photoshop. My script is based upon tables from  http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/UnstableURLs/bbr_color.html and http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/

Comment: @fmw42 I understand. Thanks a lot for your comment.